# How to implement GMSK demodulation

Tags: modulation, demodulation

I am currently trying to implement a GMSK demodulator, using Java. I am actualy trying to use the model of this block diagram. However, I really do not know what goes on within the mode selector and the differentiator. Does anyone have an understanding of this?, or is there a better method i can employ which may or may not be different from this ?

[image: GMSK Demodulator block diagram]

Comment: The top branch makes sense because GMSK is a phase modulation.  It's a funky phase modulation, but still a phase modulation.  While it is true that the derivative of phase is frequency, I would have labeled that "phase changes".  The magnitude branch does not makes sense to me because part of the point of GMSK is that it is constant amplitude.  I guess measuring the magnitude can help detect distortions, much like constant-modulus algorithm (CMA) equalization?  And I don't understand the upper/lower sideband branches at all.

Comment: Do you know of any straightforward to understand block diagram or explanation ? also, do you think it is realizable with java if I am able to get a full understanding of the concept behind it ?

Comment: Where did you find the block diagram?

Comment: I got it online. But the explanation on it wasnt enough

Comment: Where online?  Post the link.